# Python regex: Splitting by \n character as long as the \n isn't at the start

Tags: python, regex, split, newline

I have a string that I want to split by new line characters, but I want to leave the \n character in if it is at the start of the string. I know that \A matches the start of a string, but I don't know how to negate it. I'm guessing I would use something like:

```
re.split(r"(expression here) & (?<! )\n", text)
```

(I'm also leaving \n characters preceded by spaces in)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

An example:

```
"
:10 e:1110 h:1111 l:110 o:000 x:001 y:010 z:011
11111110110110000100011001010011"
```

or

```
"\n:10 e:1110 h:1111 l:110 o:000 x:001 y:010 z:011\n11111110110110000100011001010011"
```

should come out as

```
["\n:10 e:1110 h:1111 l:110 o:000 x:001 y:010 z:011","11111110110110000100011001010011"]
```

Comment: So you want to split on newlines but only leave it in if the line was otherwise empty? `line1\n\nline3` would leave one newline?

Comment: yes, that seems like it. Basically I have an encoding dictionary formatted as a string and I want to leave \n if it looks like: "\n:codehere a:othercode b:anothercode" etc.

Comment: You could help by including a couple of samples, input with expected output here.

Comment: What about multiple `\n` at the start? `"\n\n\nfoo\nbar"`

Comment: That shouldn't happen; the way my code works there will only ever be one. (Also I'm working on an example now)

Comment: @FalseAzure how about just using a lookbehind as you tried, like `(?<!\A)\n`? In fact, since `\A` matches a position, a lookahead would work just as well, I think: `(?!\A)\n`. Lookarounds can easily combined to keep your space condition: `(?<![ ])(?!\A)\n` (the square brackets are not necessary, but I prefer them for readability

Answer (score 2):

Since lookarounds don't actually advance the "cursor" of the regex engine in the subject string, you can simply check for two conditions in the same place, by writing two lookarounds after one another:

```
(?<![ ])(?<!\A)\n
```

Note that `\A` matches a position between characters instead of a character, so a lookahead works just as well:

```
(?<![ ])(?!\A)\n
```

The square brackets are not necessary, but I find they aid readability in that they make it easier to spot literal space characters.